# How to dynamically tranform data with python construct parser

Tags: python, parsing, construct

I want to dynamically transform binaries data with the construct python lib.

Here is a simple struct:

```
import construct

data = construct.Struct(
    x = construct.Int16ul
)
```

I would like to divide (applying a shift) the x data by 128 .

e.g: if x is equals to `1`, I would like to have the value `0.0078125` (1 / 128).

I tried to apply a function with the `*` operator, the function is called but the value is not saved in the `x` attribute.

```
import construct

def shift(value, context):
    return value / 128

data = construct.Struct(
    x = construct.Int16ul * shift
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `ExprAdapter` to apply custom `encode` and `decode` functions.

https://construct.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/core.html#construct.core.ExprAdapter

```
import construct

def unshift(value, context):
    return value / 128

def shift(value, context):
    return value * 128

data = construct.Struct(
    x = construct.ExprAdapter(construct.Int16ul, unshift, shift)
)
```